# Show Query statements in Rails Console with mongo_mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

With

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

you can view SQL statements in Rails Console,related [here](http://www.shanison.com/2012/03/05/show-sql-statements-in-rails-console/), but that require ActiveRecord , with mongo_mapper you don't have ActiveRecord, so how view debug of querys ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old I'm adding an answer here for anyone who comes looking later.

Based on [this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/10/09/more-mongomapper-awesomeness/) the answer is simple. In your `config/initializers/mongo.rb` file change your connection string as follows:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('mongo.example.com', 27017, :logger => logger)
```

Restart Rails and the Mongo query strings now show up in the logger.